# Custom IDM Model with PicketLink Social?

Tags: java, facebook, security, jakarta-ee, picketlink

I'm developing a JavaEE application that makes use of [JBoss PicketLink](http://www.picketlink.org) for its security framework.  I've implemented a custom IDM model to better support some custom security attributes that I need.  Now, I'd also like to add social login, through the use of [JBoss PicketLink Social](http://picketlink.org/social/sociallogin/).  I've configured my app to make use of Facebook for social login, and it is working as expected.

I've realized, however, that the `User` model object that is being used is the standard PicketLink `org.picketlink.idm.model.basic.User` class, not my customer User model object.  This is causing problems in code that relies on those custom security attributes.

Is there a way to tell PicketLink Social to make use of my custom IDM model, and not the standard PicketLink model?

Comment: you need to chage the configuration of the JBoss PicketLink Social so that it will consider your own IDM model

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of IDM model:

1. Custom: [https://github.com/lynx-r/picketlink-deltaspike-authorization-and-idm-custom-identity-model](https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-picketlink-quickstarts/tree/master/picketlink-idm-custom-identity-model)
2. Standard.

When you create custom through the above link and itegrate with the social login:https://github.com/lynx-r/picketlink-deltaspike-authorization-and-idm-custom-identity-model It would work.

look at this to integrate both configurations together : https://developer.jboss.org/message/921009?_sscc=t

Comment: I am able to create and use the custom IDM model when authenticating with username/password with no problem.  It's only when using Social login that I run into a problem.  How do I tell PicketLink Social to use the custom IDM model?  That's the issue I'm running into.

Comment: The only thing of value in the last link is a list of Maven dependencies, which I already have.